# How to set a new list activity as a view inside a tabview

Tags: android, listactivity, tabview

I am new to android. My problem is I Have a tab view which consist of two tab one show a custom view and other one shows map view. in map view i have a textview for search and a button on which when user click it will show a listview of place user typed in the in the autocomplete textview. And when the user map button on this new view it will close this listview and show the maps view again

Comment: Hard to understand what you really want.

Comment: Not enough info... How are the tabs created? are you using fragments? Activities?  One activity with several tabs?

Comment: actually i have a tabview inside an other tab view and inner tab has to replace his view with a listview created dynamically by an activity without inside the outer tab view.

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand your problem. But if your problem is setting current tab use `tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(myTab.getTag())`.

Comment: actually i am in a tab and i have to raplace the of the view of the tab with a list view which is dynamically created by an activity